# What is the name of process of Eclipse in Windows?

Tags: eclipse, process

When I start Eclipse in Windows, in task manager under processes I see *eclipse.exe* and *javaw.exe* processes.

Which is the actual process belong to Eclipse?

Comment: Why down vote?Dear down voter please add you comments.

Answer (score 4):

In short: both.

Eclipse is a product written in Java, so it requires Java VM to run. For convenience Eclipse installation contains its own native loader (eclipse.exe), which is a program that searches for a JVM library to use.
The loader can either load JVM dynamically into its own process, which results in single process being visible in task manager, or it can start Java's native launcher javaw.exe and runs Eclipse within it.

I believe that by default it will use extra javaw.exe process, but you can configure it to load the library dynamically (I like that, beacuse my process view is a bit clearer). In order to do that, you need to provide a path for the jvm.dll that you want to use. In eclipse.ini file, that is located next to eclipse.exe add

```
-vm
path_to_jdk\jre\bin\server\jvm.dll
```

(you can also use plain JRE). On my system it is in `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_25\jre\bin\server\jvm.dll`.
You can also pass this as arguments for eclipse.exe.

```
eclipse.exe -vm "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_25\jre\bin\server\jvm.dll"
```

Answer (score 3):

In Task Manager, in the *Applications* tab, if you right-click on Eclipse and select *Go To Process* it will show you what process belongs to Eclipse. Which is javaw.exe

Answer (score 1):

`eclipse.exe` is the application itself, `javaw.exe` is the jvm that runs `eclipse.exe`.
If you terminate `javaw.exe` it will terminate `eclipse.exe` also.